# Laravel mailchimp event properties are empty in template

Tags: laravel, events, properties, mailchimp, is-empty

Did my research and found nothing about this topic.

In the docs: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/track-outside-activity-events/#create-an-event

Apparently said how to create an event with options, using the library that they said which in PHP is:
`composer require mailchimp/transactional`

I can ping, do all the simple requests without problem
but some options for events are not even avaliable, for example:

```
$options = new \MailchimpMarketing\Model\Events();
```

there is no 'Model' or Events in that namespace,
then of course I looked how this event is build in other languages and I give a try to pass parameters to the event like this:

```
$options = ["name" => "my-event-name", "properties" => ['PASSLINK' => 'test']];
$response = $mailchimp->lists->createListMemberEvent(
    env('MC_AUDIENCE_ID'),
    "somemember@gmail.com",
    $options
);
```

200 status response, Event is trigger, mail received 
but in the template used, nothing is passed:

I used in that template that event property like this:
*|EVENT:PASSLINK|*

also tried lowercase
*|EVENT:passlink|*

Same result

don't know what else to do

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Seems that for a journey, the event property merge tag `*|EVENT:PROPERTY|*` does not work. They only work for classic automation. May  be that is the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have found this to be the case too.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here.
I tried all these combination of EVENT properties.
None of them works..

```
*|EVENT:name|*
*|EVENT:NAME|*
*|EVENT:PROPERTIES|*
*|EVENT:properties|*
*|EVENT:PROPERTIES:CODE|*
*|EVENT:properties:code|*
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).